# Moodle: Automating user/course creation and enrolments

Tags: moodle

I had a look at the documentation on [enrolments](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Enrolments), but all the enrolment methods seem to involve some interaction with the GUI.

Is there a way to script enrolments? Something like:

```
./moodle_do_enrolments imsdata.xml
```

Or even some web services calls that I can call from an external program?

I'd like to be able to do the following in an automated fashion:

```
1) Add a user.
2) Create a course with specified title etc.
3) Enrol that user in that course.
```

Of course at some point I'd hook this up with our user systems and other management systems, but for the moment, I'm just trying to do a proof of concept.

Where is some documentation that explains the process of automated enrolments?

Comment: AFAIK only the manual and self enrolments method requires GUI interaction. The rest are set up by the admin and then run as you just described.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to create your own PHP script: parse the XML file and use internal moodle functions to solve the problem.

**Basic ideas to solve these problems**

1) Add a user:

In user/lib.php is a method: user_create_user($user).
Just include that lib.php and find out which information is needed in the user object.

2) Create a course

In course/lib.php is a method: create_course($data, $editoroptions).
Just include that lib.php and find out which information is needed in data array.

3) Enrol a user

I created the following method to do the job for me.

```
// enroll student to course (roleid = 5 is student role)
function enroll_to_course($courseid, $userid, $roleid=5, $extendbase=3, $extendperiod=0)  {
    global $DB;

    $instance = $DB->get_record('enrol', array('courseid'=>$courseid, 'enrol'=>'manual'), '*', MUST_EXIST);
    $course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id'=>$instance->courseid), '*', MUST_EXIST);
    $today = time();
    $today = make_timestamp(date('Y', $today), date('m', $today), date('d', $today), 0, 0, 0);

    if(!$enrol_manual = enrol_get_plugin('manual')) { throw new coding_exception('Can not instantiate enrol_manual'); }
    switch($extendbase) {
        case 2:
            $timestart = $course->startdate;
            break;
        case 3:
        default:
            $timestart = $today;
            break;
    }  
    if ($extendperiod <= 0) { $timeend = 0; }   // extendperiod are seconds
    else { $timeend = $timestart + $extendperiod; }
    $enrolled = $enrol_manual->enrol_user($instance, $userid, $roleid, $timestart, $timeend);
    add_to_log($course->id, 'course', 'enrol', '../enrol/users.php?id='.$course->id, $course->id);

    return $enrolled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a GUI is not necessary, you can create an enrolment/authentication plugin to achieve this or use one of the built in ones. I'm not too familiar with the ims enrollment plugin, but the standard ldap/database plugins have scripts which can be used to automate this sync process.

See for example:
enrol/database/cli/sync.php

Comment: Dan: Can you point me to the documentation on the built in ones? Or is the only documentation in the source?